# Python import not working

Tags: python

```
spiders/
ekantipur.py
    class ekantipurSpider(XMLFeedSpider):

tests/
   responses
      __init__.py
      spiderdir
        Archive_ekantipur.html
   spiderdir_test.py
   from spiders import ekantipur
```

In the given file structure, when I try to access the class ekantipurSpider in spiderdir_test.py,i.e from spiders import ekantipur, it says following error.

```
from spiders import ekantipur
ImportError: No module named spiders
```

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` file there?

Comment: It looks like the formatting of your question isn't quite right, check your indentation please.

Comment: yes I have __init__.py file in spiders folder.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import `spiders` from the `tests` directory like that, unless you have it in your `PYTHON_PATH` environment variable. Please read about Python's [import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).

For a quick and dirty (!) fix add this at the top of your file:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
```

Or read this post about relative imports: [Import a module from a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path)

Answer (score 0):

try running the spiderdir_test.py from the parent folder of spiders and tests with this command "python -m tests/spiderdir_test". Note that you need to have __init__.py into tests folder also. Basically you will be running spiderdir_test.py as a module.

Comment: (news-scraper)➜  crawler git:(development) ✗ python -m tests/spiderdir_test.py
 /home/ramesh/.virtualenvs/news-scraper/bin/python: Import by filename   is not supported.  This is the error I got when try to run from shell.

Comment: use "spiderdir_test" instead of "spiderdir_test.py"

Comment: python -m tests/spiderdir_test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/var/www/news-scrapper/src/crawler/tests/spiderdir_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from spiders.ekantipur import ekantipur
  File "spiders/ekantipur.py", line 5, in <module>
    from crawler.items import NewsItem
ImportError: No module named crawler.items
It effects on  from crawler.items import NewsItem import.

Comment: running the module from parent folder will need all the import statement made according to the parent folder. So the crawlers folder should be parallel to the tests and parallel folder. or else try like this "from tests.crawlers.items import NewsItem", (provides crawlers is inside tests folder), according to your folder structure.